# Jenkins : How Credential plugin works with Subversion plugin

Tags: svn, jenkins, credentials

I am using Jenkins version 1.447.2. I installed latest Credentials plugin and SSH Credentials plugin. I configured everything under 'Manage Credentials' screen. Now, I expect Subversion plugin to automatically use this credential. However, it is not doing that. It is asking me to enter credential again rather than using credentials stored under Credential plugin. 
Please confirm if my understanding about Credentials plugin is correct or there is something I am missing. Is there any solution available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding might be correct some time later, but not yet.

The Credentials plugin fairly new and the Change Log of the Subversion plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) does not say anything about adding support for Credentials plugin.

I have to assume the Subversion plugin still continues to manage credentials on its own.

Answer (score 3):

I know this response maybe a little late.
The SVN plugin > 1.54 makes use of the credentials plugin. I believe git etc do as well.
If you're also using job DSL's, the ID is displayed under the "Advanced" tab. Be sure to set it when you add the credentials otherwise you'll get a UUID auto generated
eg

```
scm {
  svn {
    location ('http://example.com/your/svn/repo') {
      credentials('TheValueEntered')
      directory('.')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: better late than never :)